# Rails class comparison - If Class.children include AnotherClass.children do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, has-many-through, comparison-operators

Simple question I hope. I've a couple of classes - User and Recipe - both of which have 'ingredients' as children via has-many-through relationships. I'd like to run a comparison that checks to see if User.ingredients include the ingredients for each Recipe.

I thought a simple 'include?' query would work this out, but it's returning nil when implemented. Got a feeling this is because I'm applying it to a class rather than array (although doesn't User.ingredients return an array?!), though not sure how I should adjust this to get it working - I've tried converting items to arrays, plucking ids out, etc. but nothing has working yet.

Any help much appreciated! Steve.

Here's the controller code:

```
def meals
    @recipes = Recipe.all
    @user = current_user #from my user authentication
end
```

And the (abridged) view that's returning nil even when both contain the same ingredients:

```
    <% @recipes.each do |recipe| %>
        <% if @user.ingredients.include?(recipe.ingredients) %>
          <!-- ... -->  
                <td>
                  <%= recipe.name %>
                </td>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

One other point - testing this in the console, I've noticed running .include? on  arrays of ingredient ids don't match if they're in the wrong order. Does this also need addressing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare two array like so:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2]
c = [4,5]

a & b
#=> [1, 2]
a & c
#=> []
(a & c).empty?
#=> true
```

In this way, you can do something like:

```
<% @recipes.each do |recipe| %>
    <% unless (@user.ingredients.pluck(:id) & recipe.ingredients.pluck(:id)).empty? %>
      <!-- ... -->  
            <td>
              <%= recipe.name %>
            </td>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: Perfect - works a charm! Thanks a bunch @gabrielhilal.

Comment: As an FYI for anyone else visiting this - the answer put me on the right tracks, but threw up false positives (i.e. if just one id matches between user and recipe it shows true). I've had to adjust this so the line calculates '(@user.ingredients.pluck(:id) & recipe.ingredients.pluck(:id)) == recipe.ingredients.pluck(:id)' and I've dropped this into a helper method to tidy up a little: 'def ingredient_matcher(one, two)
    (one.ingredients.pluck(:id)) & two.ingredients.pluck(:id)) == two.ingredients.pluck(:id)
  end'  Hope that's useful to someone! Any feedback, let me know. Steve.